# function wcsncpy loses elements of the string

Tags: c

i have function for sort elements of void* string. it is comb sort (sorry for comments on russian). while it sorting String become shorter and loses elements.

```
void *SimpleSort(void *String) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    double factor = 1.2473309; // фактор уменьшения
    int step = wcslen((wchar_t *) String) - 1; // шаг сортировки
    //Последняя итерация цикла, когда step==1 эквивалентна одному проходу сортировки пузырьком
    while (step >= 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i + step < wcslen((wchar_t *) String); i++) {
            if (*(wchar_t *) (String + (i)) > *(wchar_t *) (String + (i + step))) {
                void *el = malloc(sizeof(wchar_t));
                wcsncpy(el, String + i, 1);
                wcsncpy(String + i, String + i + step, 1);
                wcsncpy(String + i + step, el, 1);
                wprintf(L"%ls\n", (wchar_t *) String);
            }
        }
        step /= factor;
    }
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", (wchar_t *) String);
    return String;
}
```

if i input asdawd, will be this
[image]

Comment: Can you describe how are organized data in `String`

Comment: String it is void*. i store there wchar_t converted to void*. i cant do wchar_t *String, because it is my task

Comment: you also did a bad thing by calling `wcslen((wchar_t *) String)` repeatedly in the loop instead of storing the size in a variable

Comment: This is your third question involving `void*` for string-like data. Whoever gives you this task does a bad job. There should be a clean software design, including the usage of correct data types.

Comment: @thebusybee it is my “laboratory work” in university. (1 course). We have not seminars only this. And they tell almost nothing. You have to find out everything yourself. Because i only have : “you should have void * string and write several functions”

Comment: If you can, drop the course. Teaching students such bad things is a crime.

Comment: "String it is void*. i store there wchar_t converted to void*. i cant do wchar_t *String, because it is my task" I will reask my question : how is organised the memory pointed by `String` ? array of pointers ? string concatenated ? other ?

Answer (score 0):

String is a void *, which is typically 32-bits or 64-bits on a modern architecture.  Why not pass in the "real" type?

(String + 1) will advance your pointer by 32- or 64- bits, because String is void *.

You are working with wchar_t, probably a 16-bit value, so any pointer or array math is incompatible between your String variable and the other variables.  What you are seeing is probably the result of alignment errors between your types, and you are hiding these alignment errors with C-casts.

Remove the dangerous casting and using the real types, instead (without compile errors), and it will start working once you have fixed the compile errors.

Comment: so https://gist.github.com/SirodgevAlex/51a66753f1be998925f519430c3494ff ?

Answer (score 0):

it is wrong to find your length so

```
length = wcslen((wchar_t *) String);
```

you should use variable for this, and it will solve